# Web page behaves differently for Safari

Tags: html, ios, safari

The following html code is a cut down version to demonstrate a problem when using it on an ipad or iphone with Safari.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
     <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8" />
         <title>Testing</title>
         <script type="text/javascript">
                                function getstuff()
                                {
document.dataentry.tandc.blur();
<!-- Show the Continue button now -->
document.getElementById("open").hidden="";
ff.style.display='block';
                           document.dataentry.sb.focus();
}
</script>
         </head>
         <body>
<div class="span8">
<div class="row">
<div class="box">
<h3>Sign Up To Access Wi-Fi</h3>
<!-- Not going via Facebook -->
<form name="dataentry" action="http://www.cavreporter.com.au:90/Portal/DoNothing.php" method="post">
     <div class="field" align="left">
     <span><input type="text" name="fn" placeholder="Name" /></span>
     </div>
     <div class="field" align="left">
     <span>
     <input type="email" name="em" id="txtEmail" placeholder="Email Address" />
     </span>
     </div>
     <div class="field" align="left">
     <span>Subscribe: <input type="checkbox" name="sb" /></span>
     <label>
     <h5>By ticking subscribe you agree to receive information</h5>
     </label>
     <input name="tc" type="hidden" />
     <button class="button" style="text-decoration: underline;" name="tandc" type="submit" onclick="getstuff()">Sign Up</button>
     </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- This is the "Enter" button for "Open" networks. -->
<div style="display:none;" id="ff">
<!-- This is the "Enter" button for "Open" networks. -->
<div class="span8">
<div class="row">
<div class="box">
<strong>By clicking Continue, you agree.</strong>
<form action="$authaction" method="get">
     <input name="tok" type="hidden" value="$tok" />
     <input name="redir" type="hidden" value="$redir" />
     <button class="button" style="text-decoration: underline;" id="open" hidden="hidden" type="submit">Continue</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The code displays a couple of text fields and a button, while the other button is presently hidden from the user. Upon entering info into the text fields click the button and the other button now appears. When using this on a Safari device the second button appears as expected and then almost immediately a new page is loaded using the address of the php routine in the action statement. Using other browsers the page is not loaded and the button appears as expected.

Am I just abusing something with the HTML standard or does Safari required something more as I don't want it to load the page.

An example of this is available at www.cavreporter.com.au:90/fu.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your button has `type="submit"` so the form is being posted.

So you can simply change your button like this:

```
<button class="button" style="text-decoration: underline;" name="tandc" type="button">Sign Up</button>
```

Where `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`

It would be good form to also catch the `submit` event on your first `form` to prevent incidental submissions.

Comment: Thanks Vinchi. I made the changes suggested but this does not fix the problem. Still loading the page when I test on an ipad or iphone.

Comment: @HarryWombat updated answer to simply change `button` element type.

Comment: Part of the problem was also related to the captive portal process the ipad and iphone like to use when they find an open Wi Fi network. If the Wi Fi network is connected to instead of using Safari the ipad/iphone will use a hybrid browser which does not support the html I was trying to use. Modified the code to suit how the captive portal browser works by removing the action & method statements and using the xmlhttpRequest instruction in the function instead. Outcome is the same for me and it works with the ipad/iphone